# Issue with linking a custom domain to APP RUNNER service

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I hosted a sample app runner service and trying to mask the service with custom domain .
I purchased a custom domain and validated the app runner certificates by  creating CNAME records in route 53. certificates are in "ACTIVE". Issue is still i am unable to launch the app runner service using custom domain . i followed the below steps in aws documentation .
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/manage-custom-domains.html .

I believe the issue is with this step in above documentation, which i am not sure how to configure this step ". In addition, add DNS target records to your DNS to target the App Runner domain. You need to add one record for the custom domain, and another for the www subdomain, if you chose this option. "

Comment: I have the same problem. I have followed all troubleshooting guides I cant find. It simply never validates my certs. It is infuriating because it takes days to find out that it failed.